# UI not updating when making HTMl request iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am scraping some HTML off a University's directory page. After the user hits the search button I want to dismiss the keyboard and add an animating activity indicator in the navigation bars right item.

I am using this code:

```
[_searchBar resignFirstResponder];

[self drawActivityIndicator];

NSString *formattedSearchText = [searchBar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];


DirectorySearch *searchEngine = [[DirectorySearch alloc]initWithSearchURL:formattedSearchText withSegmentedControlIndex:0];
```

When I remove the last line of code the search bar and activity indicator are added properly, but with that line it seems to block the UI and not update it.

The `-(id)initWithSearchURL:(NSString *)searchText withSegmentedControlIndex:(NSInteger *)index;`

method is making HTML requests.

How can I ensure that the UI is updated before running the last line of code in the snippet?

Comment: In your `initWithSearchUrl` method, you aren't making the web request on the main thread, are you?

Comment: @wottle I guess I am, its calling method/s that make a web request.

Answer (score 7):

You should do the request in background thread, and update the UI on the main thread after you receive response.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    DirectorySearch *searchEngine = [[DirectorySearch alloc] initWithSearchURL:....

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // update UI

    }
});
```

It is pretty basic stuff regarding iOS, I would recommend reading some tutorials online.